# EE 5.x - How to suppress login/logout confirmation page

Tags: expressionengine

on EE 2.x the Freemember addon allowed to directly redirect the user after login/logout to a specified page (avoiding the default login/logout confirmation page).

Since the Freemember addon is EOL, how can I achieve the same thing on EE 5.x ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the member_member_login_single($hook_data) in a custom extension to get this done. Works.

Answer (score 0):

First you could use [Custom System Messages](https://expressionengine.com/add-ons/custom-system-messages)

You can also do this with ajax (dont't have an example at hand)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the member_member_login_single hook in a simple extension and redirect it with php.

```
function member_member_login_single($hook_data)
{
    if(isset($_POST['RET'])){
          header('location: '.$_POST['RET']);
          exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: see my solution below, similar thing but I used the hook via the activate_extension() method, as per the docs. Regarding your code example: can I just overwrite a given hook by using a same name method ?

Comment: That's exactly my solution.